# Interpreting Results From Explain Analyze in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Recently did a query which took about 9 minutes to complete. Attempting to determine why, I used `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to help solve the problem. From the output, it looks as though everything has the appropriate indexes, it's just taking an extremely long time.

I've put the query and the results below. Is it just taking this long due to the amount of data? Or is there something which I am doing wrong. Does my query need to fundamentally change, in order to improve the performance?

Additional Info: PostgreSQL 10.6. System in a Xeon @ 3.4Ghz, with SSD and 24GB of memory, so it's fairly good spec desktop.

```
SELECT      s.start_date, s.end_date, s.resources, s.activity_index, r.resource_id, sa.usedresourceset 
FROM        rm_o_resource_usage_instance_splits_new s 
INNER JOIN  rm_o_resource_usage r ON s.usage_id = r.id 
INNER JOIN  scheduledactivities sa ON s.activity_index = sa.activity_index 
    AND r.schedule_id = sa.solution_id 
    and s.solution = sa.solution_id 
WHERE       r.schedule_id = 14349 
ORDER BY   r.resource_id, s.start_date
----------------------------------------------------------------
"Sort  (cost=18.01..18.01 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=541075.198..541099.504 rows=65354 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: r.resource_id, s.start_date"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8016kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..18.00 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=6.946..540671.934 rows=65354 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (s.activity_index = sa.activity_index)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3550029280"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..12.93 rows=1 width=98) (actual time=0.074..1795.054 rows=65354 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (s.usage_id = r.id)"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 248018"
"              ->  Index Scan using rm_o_resource_usage_instance_splits_new_solution_idx on rm_o_resource_usage_instance_splits_new s  (cost=0.42..4.76 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=0.032..36.395 rows=65354 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (solution = 14349)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on rm_o_resource_usage r  (cost=0.00..8.15 rows=2 width=45) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=5 loops=65354)"
"                    Filter: (schedule_id = 14349)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 332"
"        ->  Index Scan using scheduled_activities_idx on scheduledactivities sa  (cost=0.42..5.06 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.007..4.937 rows=54321 loops=65354)"
"              Index Cond: (solution_id = 14349)"
"Planning time: 1.547 ms"
"Execution time: 541104.491 ms"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your query exec plan a lot of time is spent on sorting

```
    "Sort  (cost=18.01..18.01 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=541075.198..541099.504 rows=65354 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: r.resource_id, s.start_date"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8016kB"
```

I would recommend you  to increase [work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) param for `PostgreSQL` as described [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

> If you do a lot of complex sorts, and have a lot of memory, then increasing the work_mem parameter allows PostgreSQL to do larger
>   in-memory sorts which, unsurprisingly, will be faster than disk-based
>   equivalents.
>
> This size is applied to each and every sort done by each user, and
>   complex queries can use multiple working memory sort buffers. Set it
>   to 50MB, and have 30 users submitting queries, and you are soon using
>   1.5GB of real memory. Furthermore, if a query involves doing merge sorts of 8 tables, that requires 8 times work_mem. You need to
>   consider what you set max_connections to in order to size this
>   parameter correctly. This is a setting where data warehouse systems,
>   where users are submitting very large queries, can readily make use of
>   many gigabytes of memory.
>
> log_temp_files can be used to log sorts, hashes, and temp files which
>   can be useful in figuring out if sorts are spilling to disk instead of
>   fitting in memory. You can see sorts spilling to disk using EXPLAIN
>   ANALYZE plans as well. For example, if you see a line like Sort
>   Method: external merge Disk: 7526kB in the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE,
>   a work_mem of at least 8MB would keep the intermediate data in memory
>   and likely improve the query response time (although it may take
>   substantially more than 8MB to do the sort entirely in memory, as data
>   on disk is stored in a more compact format).

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer. I changed work_mem to 16MB, then run the query. It now takes 2.6 seconds (compared to 9 minutes).

Comment: Almost no time is spent on sorting.  The sort waits 540671.934 before it has received its input, and then has generated its complete output by 541099.504, so it took less than half a second for the sort itself.

Comment: @jjanes , it's not true. This Nested Loop is a part of sorting and if you were right this 'work_mem' param would not help.

Comment: @MikeAdamenko  Increasing work_mem still might help for other reasons though, like promoting Hash Joins over Nested Loop